# formula of the Lebesgue measure of $E$ in terms of the integral regarding the Hausdorff measure

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, geometric-measure-theory

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be such that for the boundary of $E$ holds $\partial E=\{(1+u(x))x \mid x\in \partial B_1(0)\}$, where $u:\partial B_1(0)\to (-1,\infty)$ is a function of class $C^1$, and $\partial B_1(0)$ denotes the boundary of the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Denoting $|E|$ as the Lebesgue measure of $E$ and letting $B:=B_1(0)$ for short, why is
$$|E|=\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_{\partial B}(1+u(x))^nd\mathcal{H}^{n-1}\; ?$$
Here $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ denotes the $(n-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

**My try:** Let $v:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}\to (-1,\infty)$ given by $v(x)=u(\frac{x}{\|x\|}) $. Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $T(x)=(1+v(x))x$. Then, I am not sure if $T$ bijective (I think not necessarily, perhabs one has to restrict the map to $B$), but applying the change-of-variation theorem $|E|=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (\chi_E\circ T)(x)|det DT(x)|dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \chi_{T^{-1}(E)}|det DT(x)|dx=\int_B|det DT(x)|dx$, where $\chi$ stands for the characteristic function and $T^{-1}(E)=B$. Now, $DT(x)=I(1+v(x))+x\otimes \nabla v(x)$, where $I$ denotes the unit matrix and $x\otimes \nabla v(x)$ the outer product of the two vectors. Using that the determinant of any outer product is zero, it is 
$|E|=\int_B(1+v(x))^ndx$, and I think theat $v$ is the function $u$ in the formula (which I want to obtain). Then, one has to use the Coarea formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula to go further. But here, I don't know how to apply the formula concretely. My questions are:

1) Is $T(B)=E?$ Or how to fix it, if not?
2) How to finish the proof using the Coarea formula?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the first formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula#Applications) with $f=\mathbf{1}_E$ and Fubini-Tonelli you get
$$
|E| = \int_{\partial B_1} \left( \int_0^{1+u(x)} r^{n-1}\,dr \right) d\mathcal H^{n-1}(x)
= \frac1n \int_{\partial B_1} \bigl(1+u(x)\bigr)^n \,d\mathcal H^{n-1}(x) .
$$

---

**ADDENDUM**

I change the integration on $\partial B_r$ to an integration on $\partial B_1$: the substitution is $y=rx\in\partial B_r$ with $x\in\partial B_1$; this introduces a scaling factor of $r^{n-1}$.

Notice that $\mathbf{1}_E(rx)=[\![r\leq1+u(x)]\!]$, where $[\![\,\cdot\,]\!]$ denotes the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

$$
\begin{split}
|E|
&= \int_0^\infty \int_{\partial B_r} \mathbf{1}_E(y) \,d\mathcal H^{n-1}(y) \,dr \\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_{\partial B_1} \mathbf{1}_E(rx) r^{n-1}\,d\mathcal H^{n-1}(x) \,dr \\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_{\partial B_1} [\![r\leq1+u(x)]\!] r^{n-1}\,d\mathcal H^{n-1}(x) \,dr \\
&= \int_{\partial B_1} \int_0^{1+u(x)}r^{n-1} \,dr \,d\mathcal H^{n-1}(x) \\
&= \frac1n \int_{\partial B_1} \bigl(1+u(x)\bigr)^n \,d\mathcal H^{n-1}(x) .
\end{split}
$$

Comment: thank you. How exactly do you obtain the first equality? You change the order of integration, but how do you obtain the limits 0 and 1+$u(x)$, and $r^{n-1}$? (I also don't understand what the R is in the formula in wikipedia).

Comment: @TheAppliedTheoreticalOne Hi, I've added all the intermediate steps. Is it clearer now? This should explain the appearance of $1+u(x)$ and $r^{n-1}$. But I don't understand which $R$ are you referring to in a formula in Wikipedia

Comment: thank you very much, now I everything is clear. I was referring to the first formula in the "Applications" section here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula and I was wondering if with S is meant the (n-1)-Hausdorff measure or not (but ok, it is).

Comment: @TheAppliedTheoreticalOne Yes, in that formula $dS$ stands for $d\mathcal H^{n-1}$. I think they've chosen $dS$ because it recalls _surface area_, so that it's more familiar to people using it, let's say, in physics.

Comment: okay, sounds reasonable